# How do you read a table from a certain part in a word document using python-docx?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-docx

I am reading from a word file using Python with many tables in the document. I need to extract data only from certain tables, depending on the sections they appear in. Is there any way to search through the file, reach a certain line, and read the table that appears after the line?

For example, if the word document is something like:

1
2
3
[table]
4
5
6
[table]

would I be able to read the table specifically after the '6'?

Reading the 'second table' would not work, because the number of tables that appear before that table is arbitrary; I need to read it because it appears after the '6'.

Comment: Is there anything else that would uniquely identify the table? (i.e. something in the cells?)

Comment: No, there is nothing within the table that would uniquely identify the table. The identifiers are external, i.e. a 'paragraph' the line above the table.

Comment: Is the document split into sections that can be identified by `document.sections`?

Comment: No, the document is not.

Comment: You will need to find something to uniquely identify the tables, or get all the data from every table and then filter it afterward. Without a more in depth description of your problem we can't help much more

Comment: The document is also split up by headings, if there is any way to utilize those, and parse data exclusively under certain headings.

Comment: In my use of python-docx, it appears to treat text (`paragraphs`) completely separate from `tables`. So no, I don't believe using headings is a possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code here may be of interest: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/276#issuecomment-199502885.

What you're looking for, I believe, is a way to iterate the *block level* items in a document, in the order they appear. A Word document has two types of block-level items, paragraphs and tables. The function at the link above allows you to iterate those in document order.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.